# keyup, keydown on mobile devices

Tags: android, jquery, keydown, keyup

I have the following jquery code that are connected to different inputs (#min_c, ...).

```
$(document).on('keyup',"#min_c, #min_u, #min_r, #min_m", delay(function (e) { ...
```

Works great via desktop but not via mobile devices. I already tested it with the keyup input combination like:

```
$(document).on('keyup input',"#min_c, #min_u, #min_r, #min_m", delay(function (e) { ...
```

but no success at all ... the event is not triggered on android smartphones via android chrome browser.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks in advance and best greetings!